# Looking for a story of an academy that features kids learning about flying space

Tags: story-identification

I read this two or three years ago, but I think it was published before that. This story is probably the only book the author writes for a younger audience. I don't read her (I think it's a she) other books, so I'm unfamiliar with who she is, this story was suggested to me by a friend.

What I remember:

- The main character is a girl
- She goes to an academy in place of her brother because he wishes to do something else (or a physical disability, I think)
- Has to dress up as a boy because it is a school for only boys
- She meets this guy (North, I think he's called?) in the academy
- North protects her from a lot of the bullies
- She visits North's home planet
- At his home planet, they get mad at each other, I don't remember why
- They go back to the academy, North eventually finds out she's a girl
- A bunch of misunderstandings follow
- Happy ending like all romance books

Is there a book that matches this description?

Comment: [All Men of Genius](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/AllMenOfGenius) but it doesn't involve multiple planets or space travel afaik...

Comment: Yentl in space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Academy](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15792218-the-academy) by Emmaline Andrews and Evangeline Anderson. It was published in 2012, which fits the time you remember reading it.

[image: The Academy]

> My name is Kris Jameson and I’m a student at the Royal Academy. I’m at the top of all my classes, what they call a “model student.” There’s only one problem—the Academy is an all boys school and I’m a girl.
>
> It started as a prank when I took my brother’s place. But things got complicated when I caught Broward, the school bully, in a compromising position. They got even worse when I was assigned my roommate—the handsome but enigmatic North who saved me several times from the bully’s attacks.
>
> Now the consequences of my deception are coming back to haunt me. The penalty for fraud at this exclusive school is much worse than simple expulsion—I could lose a hand. Worse, so could my beloved brother.
>
> With so much at stake, it’s imperative that I keep my secret safe. And the person I’m closest to, North, is the one I have to be most wary of.
>
> The trouble is, I think I’m falling in love with him…

I confess I haven't read this. I searched for [space academy brother](https://www.google.com/search?q=space%20academy%20brother%20%22science%20fiction%22%20site%3Agoodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F&rlz=1C1VDKB_enGB1019GB1023&oq=space%20academy%20brother%20%22science%20fiction%22%20site%3Agoodreads.com%2Fbook%2Fshow%2F) on the Goodreads site and as luck would have it this was one of the top results.